# Using Mockito, how do I intercept a callback object on a void method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, callback, jaas, mockito

I'm using mockito to test a legacy JAAS/LDAP login module.

The `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler` interface defines the function:

```
void handle(javax.security.auth.callback.Callback[] callbacks)
```

I'm expecting `callbacks` to contain a `NameCallback`, which is the object that needs to be manipulated to pass the test.

Is there a way to mock this effectively, or would I be better off with a stubbed implementation of `CallbackHandler`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

For functions returning `void`, use [doAnswer()](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer))

```
doAnswer(...).when(mockedObject).handle(any(Callback[].class));
```

And an `Answer` that performs the interception must go in as the parameter to `doAnswer`, e.g. as an anonymous class:

```
new Answer() {
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
      Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
      Mock mock = invocation.getMock();
      return null;
  }}
```

In this case `args` will be the array `Callback[]`!

Comment: Note for everybody who skips straight to the answers: the handle() method should be substituted with whatever method you are using on your class. I was briefly confused because I used handle() thinking it was a Mockito function.

Comment: any proper example please?