# How to mock the parameter in an anonymous callback by using mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, callback, mockito, junit4

I want to unit test my code below with Mockito, could anyone let me know how I can mock the response from the callback, which is anonymous in my code? Particularly, how can I verify if doSomethingOnResponse() gets called with the mocked response?

```
public void runTask() {
    Data data = null;

    ClassA objA = new ClassA(new Callback() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(Response response) {
            data = getSomethingFromResponse(response);
         }
    };

    //this is a synchronous call     
    objA.run();

    doSomethingElse(data); //data gets assigned from the callback
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does your use-case match [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13616547/1426891)? You're passing the Callback as a constructor argument rather than a method argument, but the answers are the same--use an ArgumentCaptor or an Answer.

Comment: Yes, I have to pass the Callback to the constructor due to the design restriction, so if I mimic the use case you mentioned, how can I do the when part which is for a method call?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Where is `onResponse` invoked? In your example code, you don't use the `response` argument at all - is that intentional? Perhaps a real-life (compilable) example would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I just missed the "response" in the doSomethingOnResponse(response), it does get used, and that's what I am trying to verify.

Comment: Could anyone please give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: Your question alludes to (1) some enclosing class, (2) ClassA, (3) Callback, (4) Response, and (5) Data. Which _unit_ are you trying to test? Where would `doSomethingElse` and `getSomethingFromResponse` be defined?

Comment: Hi Jeff, getSomethingFromResponse(response) is a private method that parses the data from the raw response, I want to unit test if it gets invoked on getting the response from the callback. I also want to unit test if it parses the response correctly. Thanks!

Comment: I'd also want to unit test the runTask() as a whole.