# Unit Testing static methods with callbacks

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

What is the best way to test the following static method with a callback

```java
Service.doAction(request, Callback<Response> callback);
```

I am aware of similar questions around mocking and testing [non-static objects and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616547/calling-callbacks-with-mockito) but this is specific to static methods. Is there any way to use Powermock with Answers or ArgumentCaptor to achieve this?

Comment: I don't get it. What do you want exactly to test? Wether the callback is called?

Comment: Test everything, if the callback is made, if the parameters are correct, if the result of the callback is correct.

Comment: Is the problem that the callback is asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

You claim you want to **test** the `static` method. So you most likely will not *mock* it as well, right?

What you **do** want to mock will be the *parameters* passed into the method - `request` and `callback`. But that's just the same as mocking any other parameters:

- Create a mock
- Define the behaviour
- pass it in
- verify the results / methods calles on the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Create a mocked request, and the callback with the code you need to test that it's being called and being called with the right results, then just call it, exaclty as you posted.